Ignore changes to files that are cloned from a git repo
I'd like to provide people with files in a repo that won't fire a modified notification to them in GitHub if/when they modify them.
Apparently declaring the folder in a .gitignore file will only ignore changes to NEW files that weren't directly included in the original repo.
How can I allow people to make changes to files that come with the repo without the modify notification showing in GitHub Desktop? Thanks
